# DotNetCore Identity Multi Tenancy with Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm building a B2B SaaS application and trying to implement authorization.

Users will have their own `login` and will be associated with at least one `account`. The `login` being specific to the person and the `account` being specific to the organisation/billing entity. Many `logins` can be a member of an `account` and a single `login` can have access to many `accounts`, a simple many to many relationship.

How do I make this work with Identity Roles and Claims?

My edge case scenario which I can't quite get my head around is if `login A` is associated with `account A` as an administrator and `account B` as a read only user, then from my understanding of how the out of the box identity system is working, when `login A` is working under `account B`, his role would be incorrectly reported be as an administrator and not as a read only user as the roles/claims implementation is not multi tenanted.

I've done quite a bit of digging on this and can only find information/examples on this where a single user only operates under a single tenant (although there are multiple tenants within the system).

Can anybody point me in the right direction or am I barking up the wrong tree by trying to use the out of the box identity system?

Comment: I think building your own system will take less time than working around the out of the box identity system.

Answer (score 0):

In the new identity system `roles` are just `claims`... But roles are not your friend in this scenario. Claims are. When the use logs in you add x claims for Account A and y claims for Account B and so on. Then on `Acccount A` you check for that particular claim and authorize appropriately.

Example:

Account A claims could be like

> over18,canwrite_accountA

Account B claims can be like

> read_only_account_B

That way the user should have appropriate access based on which claim you are authorizing over.

Comment: So you're parsing strings to determine authorization? Somehow that doesn't seem like a very tidy solution!